# Deduce return type of operator/function for templates

Tags: c++, templates

Is something like this possible?

```
// We can even assume T and U are native C++ types
template<typename T, typename U>
magically_deduce_return_type_of(T * U) my_mul() { return T * U; }
```

Or would somebody have to hack up a return_type struct and specialize it for every pair of native types?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Heard of [`decltype`](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#suffix-return)?

In `C++0x`  you can do

```
template<class T, class U>
auto mul(T x, U y) -> decltype(x*y)
{
    return x*y;
}
```

Comment: Is something like this possible without C++0x?

Comment: @Chris : Nopes! This feature is available in MSVC++[2010] and in g++ (version 4.3 and higher).

Comment: no, that's one of the reasons that the "auto" and "decltype" items have been added is to address this shortcoming that caused issues with areas like generic programming and having to guess complexe types like container iterators, etc. The non standard operator "typeof" existed in some compilers to support this but it has now been standardized for our pleasure.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this in non `C++0x` code:

```
template<typename T, typename U> class Mul
{
  T t_;
  U u_;
public:
  Mul(const T& t, const U& u): t_(t), u_(u) {}
  template <class R>
  operator R ()
  {
    return t_ * u_;
  }
};

template<typename T, typename U>
Mul<T, U> mul(const T& t, const U& u)
{
  return Mul<T, U>(t, u);
}
```

Usage:
    char t = 3;
    short u = 4;
    int r = mul(t, u);

Here we have two type deductions. We implicitly declare return type by usage, not exactly decltype(T*U)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, so I had to come up with a non C++0x way. I ended up doing something like this.

```
template<typename T> struct type_precedence { static const int value = -1; };
template< > struct type_precedence<long double> { static const int value = 0; };
template< > struct type_precedence<double> { static const int value = 1; };
template< > struct type_precedence<float> { static const int value = 2; };
template< > struct type_precedence<unsigned long long> { static const int value = 3; };
template< > struct type_precedence<long long> { static const int value = 4; };
template< > struct type_precedence<unsigned long> { static const int value = 5; };
template< > struct type_precedence<long> { static const int value = 6; };
template< > struct type_precedence<unsigned int> { static const int value = 7; };
template< > struct type_precedence<int> { static const int value = 8; };
template< > struct type_precedence<unsigned short> { static const int value = 9; };
template< > struct type_precedence<short> { static const int value = 10; };
template< > struct type_precedence<unsigned char> { static const int value = 11; };
template< > struct type_precedence<char> { static const int value = 12; };
template< > struct type_precedence<bool> { static const int value = 13; };

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename T, typename U, bool t_precedent = ((type_precedence<T>::value) <= (type_precedence<U>::value))>
struct precedent_type { 
    typedef T t; 
};
template<typename T, typename U>
struct precedent_type<T,U,false> { 
    typedef U t;
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename T, typename U>
typename precedent_type<T,U>::t my_mul() { return T * U; }
```

EDIT: Here's the example - I'm actually doing this to multiply vectors. It looks something like this:

```
template<int N, typename T, typename U>
vec<N,typename precedent_type<T,U>::t> operator *(const vec<N,T>& v1,const vec<N,U>& v2) {
    ...
}

...

double3 = float3 * double3;
float4 = float4 * int4;
etc.
```

Comment: could you provide an example how you would use my_mul()?

Comment: you could let the compiler deduce the type of result passing a variable to store the result by reference to the function: `mult(result_double3, float3, double3)`. Not convenient syntax, but would save time on hand hacking.

Answer (score 1):

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#decltype

Answer (score 0):

pre-C++0x

I don't know exactly what you want to accomplish, so:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void my_mul(T t, U u, bool& overflow) 
{
    my_mul_impl(t*u, overflow);
}

template<typename TmultU>
void my_mul_impl(TmultU mult, bool& overflow)
{
    //here you know the type and can do something meta-weird :)
    if(mult > type_traits<TmultU>::max_allowed_in_my_cool_program())
       overflow = true;
}
```

There is [more](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/foreach2.html)